# How to change Flat Rate into price range?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to change my Flat Rate from $5

into this table

Product Total= Shipping Cost

- $1-$24.99 = $2.95
- $25-$49.99 = $4.95
- $50-$74.99 = $7.95
- $75-$99.99 = $10.95
- $100-$149.99 = $13.95
- $150-$199.99 =$16.95
- $200- and up = $18.95

How can I do that?

I'm using Magento v1.7.0.2

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sir, are looking for table rates!

These can be easily configured with a .csv file and then uploaded to your store.

This article should get you pointed in the right direction: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-set-up-table-rate-shipping

Comment: Enalds.Table rate is very used full